# Need sudo access on macOS - Installing Hashcat through Brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, password-hash, hashcat

I am trying to install Hashcat using the instructions on Brew: https://brewinstall.org/install-hashcat-on-mac-with-brew/

When I enter the first command:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
on terminal, it says:
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user myname to be an Administrator)!

However, I am already an administrator when I check in Users&Groups in Systems Preferences. Typing `sudo whoami` also gives me back `root`

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure all you have to do is add sudo in front of the command like this:

```
sudo ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```